# Prevent clipping the absolute positioned child widget by the parent

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget, qlayout

I'm trying to create a layout where is existing a row, and this row should contain an absolute positioned button which should be placed outside of this row.

Here is the simple schema

[image]

I did it by just pushing a child button into the parent button (I'm not sure that it's a correct solution) and moved it to some absolute coordinates.
It works but, unfortunately, the child button is clipping by the parent. So it's like `overflow: hidden` in CSS. But in case of QT I couldn't found how to disable this behavior.

Here is the demo of my current QUI

[image]

Is there exists any way to solve it? Or should I just use some widget combination with the empty spacer etc.?

```
    btn = QPushButton("button")

    test = QPushButton("X")
    test.setParent(btn)
    test.move(200, 5)

    self.layout.addWidget(btn)
```

Full code of the UI class (minimal reproducible example)

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton("button")

        test = QPushButton("X")
        test.setParent(btn)
        test.move(200, 5)

        self.layout.addWidget(btn)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,74)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        # self.layout.addStretch(-1)
        self.setMinimumSize(640,400)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

Comment: You could try using a `QGridLayout` and put all the large button in the first column, and the two smaller ones in the second one.

Comment: S. Nick. added a minimal reproducible example. Hope it helps
@Heike - thanks for the advice, but I wondered if there are existing any other way to prevent the absolute btn clipping ?

Comment: @Velidan I don't think you can draw a child widget outside the boundaries of the parent widget. To draw `test` completely, You could increase the minimum height of `btn` so that `test` to fall completely within the boundaries of `btn`. Otherwise, You could make `btn` and `test` siblings by adding them both to another widget.

Comment: yeah, I see. Pity, I though that it's possible like in case of css. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the advice of @Heike is absolutely correct and you should not look for wrong solutions.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(640,400)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)        

        btn = QPushButton("button")   

        test = QPushButton("X")
        test.setParent(btn)
#        test.move(200, 5)

#        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout = QGridLayout()        
        self.layout.addWidget(btn,  0,  0, 1, 10)
        self.layout.addWidget(test, 0, 11, 1,  1)           

        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,74) 
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just calculated the width of the button which should be "outside" and spacing between this btn and the big button. eg 15 width+15 spacing = 30 (for instance)
then I increased a witdh of the container to 60, and just added left-padding: 30px to this container.

Btw. what are these props meaning? Could you please describe me a bit? Regarding docs :   int fromRow, int fromColumn, int rowSpan, int columnSpan, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0
you set it to column №10 ?
`self.layout.addWidget(btn,  0,  0, 1, 10)` 
`self.layout.addWidget(test, 0, 11, 1,  1) `